# Is it possible to install LLVM and Clang on a USB drive?

Tags: installation, usb, clang

I recently installed Python3 in a local folder, as opposed to the entire system, on a shared hosting account and everything worked out perfectly. I was wondering if a similar thing could be done with LLVM and Clang. Instead of a local folder, I wanted to install them on a USB drive. My sysadmin doesn't want to install Clang system-wide because he doesn't want to risk breaking anything. Also, my disk quota is only about 200MiB. I want to use Clang because it outputs way more descriptive errors than GCC.

Has anyone ever tried doing this? Does anyone have any guidance? Any warnings? Is this even possible? Ideally, I was thinking I could do something like this.

`/mnt/usb/clang code.c -o code`

Answer (score 0):

Sure it possible.  Your biggest problem will probably be getting the package to install where you wnat it to.  Once on the usb, you should 1)ensure the mount of the usb does NOT have the "noexe" option, 2)tweak your PATH  environment variable to include the usb directory containing the executable, and 3)Add any necessary environment variables like LD_LIBRARY_PATH to allow the linker to pick up any needed libraries.